# Automatically open the exported file as soon as `org-export-dispatch` succeeds

Tags: org-export

What is the simplest way to configure `org-mode` to automatically open the exported file as soon as `org-export-dispatch` succeeds?

Comment: I don't understand the question: every export dispatch command allows you to export to a buffer, export to a file or export to a file and open the resulting file. Isn't this last option  enough for your purposes? If not, why not? If you have additional requirements, please edit the question and add them.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your request to be to open-and-display the exported file.  Also, you don't provide a particular use-case, so I have assumed use of `org-publish-project'.  Our goal can be achieved using defadvice.

Your request appears to be an anti-goal of org-mode.  The docstring for `org-export-show-temporary-export-buffer' says

```
When Org exports to a file, the buffer visiting that file is never
shown, but remains buried.
```

In the default code-path for `org-publish-project', the special form`save-excursion' is called which will revert any change to the display.  That means that we need to switch buffers there.

The following achieves our goal:

```
(defadvice org-export-to-file (after open-file activate)
  ;;; Need to save the buffer name for later...
  (setq realraptor/org-project-buffer (find-file-noselect file t)))  

(defadvice org-publish-project (after open-file activate)
  (message "Advice on org-export-project called")
  (switch-to-buffer realraptor/org-project-buffer))
```